# Ideas on how I can fragment captured network traffic?

Tags: network, linux, attacks, ids, snort

I am trying to create a lab environment where I can analyze common IDS solutions (starting with Snort specifically) and their ability to reassemble fragmented IP trains. I have a collection of malicious pcaps, which when ran with tcpreplay, create events and fire alerts, as expected.

I am trying to find a way to fragment all IP packets in my pcaps to test the frag3 preprocessor in Snort. This way, I can determine which reassembly engine Snort is using and test things like exploits and shellcode and Snort's ability to reassemble properly.

So far I have tried using fragroute, but I only seem to be fragmenting layer 2. I have tried using the fragroute engine with tcpreplay but cannot get the engine to compile with tcpreplay.
My initial idea was to use Scapy to loop through IP packets and fragment them that way but I am stuck.

Comment: Have you tried using ip_frag in fragroute?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to go with the Scapy option. It is less painful in the long run and gives very very granular control over packets. If you want to test fragmentation for the purpose of bypassing IDS, you are going to need a LOT of trial and error, changing many and multiple fields (checksums, header length, packet length) and at least for scalability, you will not want to fragment existing pcap files one by one. You mentioned that you are stuck with Scapy, but why exactly?

In any case, wireedit at `https://wireedit.com` is one of the best tools to manage and edit pcap files.

Answer (score 0):

For testing firewalls, I generate my own scripts using [hping](http://0daysecurity.com/articles/hping3_examples.html).

One of the options is to fragment traffic (`-f`) and you can set the data size (`-d`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, however not what I am after. I would like to alter already captured traffic, not necessarily create my own. With hping, I could send looped packets, but I am wanting to create fragmented traffic from non-fragmented pcaps. Hope that helps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [IPFragUtil](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/IPFragUtil) which does exactly what you ask and supported on Linux. You can easily fragment all packets using the command:

```
./IPFragUtil your_pcap_file.pcap -o fragmented_traffic.pcap -s [frag_size]
```